# How to make a left join using eloquent in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to make some query using left join, but in case I still confused how to do that in eloquent laravel, well go through into my model so that all of you know my problem.

Oh ya before I show my model, I wanna tell something about my tables, so I have 2 table in my database, one called CommonUnit (parent), and the last called Item (child), so I have the model like this :

`CommonUnit.php`:

```
public function item_left_join()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'id_common_unit');
}
```

`Item.php`:

```
// nothing happened in here
```

And my controller looks like this :

```
$masterCommonUnit = CommonUnit::select('common_units.id_common_unit', 'common_units.name_unit', 'common_units.information_unit', 'common_units.created_by', 'common_units.edited_by')
                            ->with(['item_left_join' => function ($query) {
                                $query->select('id_item', 'item_id_common_unit');
                            }])
                            ->orderBy($order, $dir)
                            ->groupBy('common_units.id_common_unit')
                            ->get()
                            ->toArray();

$return response()->json([
    'a' => $masterCommonUnit
], 200);
```

And for the result is not okay enough, because when I already look my result at the console, the result is like this :

[image: my result query at the console]

Why my result to be like that? the result shouldn't be like that, the result must grouping by they are `id_common_unit` but my children result is not grouping as well, any problem with my code? or something else make my query is not working? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your problem by adding your existing database scheme ( tables, and rows ) using an ASCII table ( i.e. https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables ).

Also, please include a sample output that you would like to see after executing the query.

Comment: okey sir, I'll add my detail for the next problem, thanks for that sir, my problem is already clear

Comment: Ok sir, now I understand why there is not even a single comment in two days. It's over clear.